# Select Entrys by Time

Tags: qgis, select, time, format

I want to select entries of my GPS-Point data only recorded from `7 a.m. to 7 p.m.` and close out all others. Right now, its in a String format (00:00:06).
I tried `"time": >= '07:00:00'` and `"time": <= '19:00:00' "`, but it doesnt work. I think, its because of the wrong format of the column. Maybe it works with an integer or a daytime format? I tried to convert, but i did not find a way until now.

I am using Qgis 3.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Field Calculator to create another field that does not have the colon characters in it, like this:

```
replace("time", ':', '')
```

[image: field calculator]

Then you can use the select by attribute to select between 70000 and 190000: 
[image: select by attribute]